# Why am I getting 2 slid shows on web page?

Tags: html, css

I recently added a slide show as a background on my webpage. I took the code from a tutorial and added my information. After I did the css and took a look at the page I had 2 slideshows. One that covered the entire page (what I wanted) and another behind my sites header. I thought it might be because I had everything in a background container but when I took that away the second slide show just appeared over my header. I can't figure out how to get rid of the second slide show.

Her is my code for the slide show:

```
<div id="background-container">
        <ul class="cb-slideshow">
            <li>
                <span>Image 01</span>
                <div>
              <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/image_10.jpg" style="width:100%">
                    <h3>Class</h3>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span>Image 02</span>
              <div>
                <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/image_1.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <h3>Rosary</h3>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <span>Image 03</span>
              <div>
                <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/image_2.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <h3>Sets</h3>
              </div>
                </li>
            <li>
              <span>Image 04</span>
              <div>
                <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/image_3.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <h3>Bracelets</h3>
              </div>
                </li>
            <li>
              <span>Image 05</span>
              <div>
                <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/PB0002.jpg" style="width:100%">
                  <h3>Sophistication</h3>
              </div>
                </li>
            <li>
              <span>Image 06</span>
              <div>
                <img class="sh_pic" src="pictures/gallary/necklace-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <h3>Necklace</h3>
              </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
#background-container  {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
}
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(pictures/gallary/pattern.png) repeat top left;
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family: brock;
    font-size: 160px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: black;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { background-image: url(pictures/gallary/necklace-1.jpg) }
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/PB0002.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/image_3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/image_2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/image_1.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url(pictures/gallary/image_10.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.05);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.05);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
    }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(200px);
    }
    8% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    19% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-400px);
    }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 100px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 50px }
```

Maybe there is to much code and I just don't see it. 
Any ideas how to get rid of the second one?

Comment: Did you add any JavaScript in the process as well?

Comment: Acrually I didn't add any. The acutal slide shows run perfect except I have two of them.